# Windows Phone/Silverlight: check whether a control has input focus

Tags: silverlight, textbox, windows-phone, focus, controls

How to know whether a control such as TextBox has the input focus in a Windows Phone Silverlight app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use FocusManager

```
bool b = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == myTextbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are events like GotFocus and LostFocus for controls.

If you subscribe to these events they automatically get called when your input receives or looses focus

you can use those events for your purpose.

XAML Declaration

```
<TextBox Name="myTextbox" GotFocus="myTextbox_GotFocus" />
```

and inside the cs

```
  private void myTextbox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

  }

  private void ContentPanel_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

  }
```

Comment: I do know about this, but I'd like to do what I need without adding even handlers to the existing controls.

Comment: @TecMan Did you try my answer?